# How do I build software with no "configure", only "configure.in.in"?

Tags: linux, build

Fedora 12
kernel 2.6.32.9-70.fc12.i686

I have downloaded [*kdirstat*](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/kdirstat.html) [from cvs](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=30290). And I want to build and install it.

However, there is no configure script file. The only file I have is a *configure.in.in*.

How can I create the configure script file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by looking at the ['cvs of kdirstat'](http://kdirstat.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/kdirstat/kdirstat/admin/cvs.sh?revision=1.7&content-type=text/plain) i would guess that you should call

```
% bash admin/cvs.sh dist
```

which should create 'configure' and everything else.